# ¿Cuando se usa pool de conexiones se debe liberar la conexión con el método .close()? JAVA JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc

Tengo una gran duda con respecto a eso, e visto en varios tutoriales o guías que cuando se usa pool de conexiones no liberan la conexión, alguien me podría clarar ese punto. Gracias.

Comment: Si estás utilizando persistencia e inyección de dependencias Spring se encarga de cerrar las conexiones. Por ejemplo utilizando `@PersistenceContext` sobre un `EntityManager` spring se encargará de todo ese trabajo.

Comment: Generalmente cuando usas pool de conexiones lo que haces es que el servidor destino te brinde el soporte para lo mismo y bajo ese perfil el conector de java se adecua.....De esta forma se liberan las conexiones de la memoria del servidor ya que es quien gestiona las misma y este solo te da una ruta para que hagas la solicitud mediante sentencia SQL a traves del conector de java, JNDI

Answer (score 0):

De forma "natural", la memoria del pool se libera cuando la aplicación finaliza.

Pero creo que es una muy buena práctica que tú hagas el close() en el momento que corresponda, para asegurarte de de que se realizan las operaciones pertinentes que deban hacerse para finalizar la conexión con la base de datos. Así no sólo liberas memoria de tu aplicación, también en el sistema gestor de bases de datos.

Answer (score 0):

El pool de conexión se utiliza para evitar lo que bien dices en tu comentario `cerrar la conexión`, la idea es que cuando creamos una conexión esto tiene un coste de recursos y si vuestra aplicación es muy transaccional eso ralentizaría las consultas porque cada una abriría y cerraría la conexión, si a eso le sumamos un entorno `multi-hilo` para acelerar las transacciones en paralelo o múltiples aplicaciones consultando al mismo tiempo provocarías que se abrieran `n` cantidad de conexiones sin control, ahí es donde entra el pool de conexión para mantener un determinado número de conexiones que la base datos pueda manejar, incluso si utilizas un servidor de aplicaciones como `Glassfish, Willfly, etc` se puede compartir el pool de conexión entre 2 o más aplicaciones, con esto se gana `control` al definir el número máximo de conexiones disponibles evitando que cada aplicativo cree la cantidad de conexiones que desee comprometiendo la estabilidad de la base de datos, `flexibilidad` permitiendo compartir las conexiones evitamos que si un aplicativo no está transaccionando las conexiones se destinen a los aplicativos que si las necesitan como un sistema por turnos y `mantenibilidad` porque hay un único punto de configuración si necesitamos aumentar el número de conexiones o si cambiamos de base de datos redirigir las conexiones.